# How to add image selector field in k2 example plugin?

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, plugin, k2

i am working on k2 example plugin, i want to add image selector field in k2 category section, i have already created html contents and text fields using the same and is working ,
but i don't know that we write as type for XML field. plz help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a image selector which uses Joomla's built-in Media Manager, you can use the following form field type in your XML:

```
<field name="myimage" type="media" directory="stories" />
```

For more information on the *media* type form field, please read the Joomla documentation:

http://docs.joomla.org/Media_form_field_type